# in pom.xml for maven configuration I cannot understand $

Tags: maven

Some guy while teaches how to use maven use the following code.

The problem it that what is the ${} in version tag.

It seems it is a value of a variable, if it is so how can I define some for myself

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
  <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
  <version>${microprofile.version}</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [property](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) defined under the properties tag in the project tag.

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
</project>
```

For the example above, `${maven.compiler.source}` would be replaced with 1.7. These are usually used to define constants that are used in multiple locations to facilitate changing it later on.